# How to extract directory from property?

Tags: msbuild

I have a property `GroupProj` storing a full path name.  How can I extract the directory of the property?

I have the following code, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <GroupProj>C:\development\project\default.groupproj</GroupProj> 
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="Default">
    <Message Text="Echo: $(GroupProj->'%(RootDir)')" />
</Target>
```

---

I will describe my actual intention of doing so.  Perhaps there is a way to do the job that I am not aware of.

I have a `Delphi` groupproj (MSBuild project) file, `C:\development\project\default.groupproj`:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Projects Include="project1.dproj">
            <Dependencies/>
        </Projects>
        <Projects Include="project2.dproj">
            <Dependencies/>
        </Projects>
        <Projects Include="project3.dproj">
            <Dependencies/>
        </Projects>
    </ItemGroup>
    ...
</Project>
```

There are other 3 `MSBuild` files (`project1.dproj`, `project2.dproj` and `project3.dproj`) stored in same folder as `default.groupproj`.

I create a `MSBuild` project file (c:\test.targets):

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="3.5">
    <Import Project="$(GroupProj)" />
    <Target Name="Build">
        <MSBuild BuildInParallel="True" Projects="project1.dproj;project2.dproj;project3.dproj"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

And execute as:

```
c:\> msbuild /p:GroupProj="C:\development\project\default.groupproj" test.targets
```

The execution shall fail as `MSBuild` can't find `projectN.dproj` file.  The issue shall be the working directory isn't set to `default.groupproj`.

One straight solution come into my mind is to extract directory of $(GroupProj) and concat to there `projectN.dproj` file.

That's the whole story of my question.

Comment: Try just `<Message Text="Echo: $(GroupProj->%(RootDir))" />`. Close voters, it's not a duplicate! OP wants to print out a [`well-known item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313.aspx) `%(RootDir)` in the MSBuild.

Comment: @TLama Thank you for correcting me. The Delphi tag was what confused me I guess. I've removed it now.

Comment: @Chau, what exactly are you going to echo ? You can get those well-known metadata only for items (nodes of `<ItemGroup>`), but it's not clear to me what you're going to output. Could you elaborate this, please ?

Comment: @TLama: I just want to extract the directory name of GroupProj and keep in a property for other purpose.  Something like `Dirname` task in `Apache ANT` is good enough.

Comment: @TLama: I edit the question to describe what I really want.  Thanks

Comment: @TLama you are mixing Properties ($) with Items (@). Properties doesn't have metadata (%).

Comment: @Rolo: So there is no way to extract directory name from a property?

Comment: @ChauCheeYang You can't get the directory from a property. You need to convert your property to an Item. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <GroupProj>C:\development\project\default.groupproj</GroupProj> 
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="Build">
        <CreateItem Include="$(GroupProj)">
          <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="ItemFromProp"/>
      </CreateItem>

      <Message Text="1. @(ItemFromProp -> '%(RootDir)%(Directory)')"/>
      <Message Text="2. %(ItemFromProp.RootDir)%(ItemFromProp.Directory)"/>
      <Message Text="3. %(ItemFromProp.Identity)"/>
      <Message Text="4. %(ItemFromProp.FullPath)"/>
      <Message Text="5. %(ItemFromProp.FileName)"/>
      <Message Text="6. %(ItemFromProp.Extension)"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

EDIT:

To build the projects in parallel try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <Target Name="GetGroupProjPath">
    <ItemGroup>
      <GroupProj Include="$(GroupProj)" />
      <GroupProjPath Include="@(GroupProj->'%(Directory)')" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
      <GroupProjPath>@(GroupProjPath->'%(RootDir)%(Identity)')</GroupProjPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>

  <Import Project="$(GroupProj)" />
  <Target Name="GetDProjs" DependsOnTargets="GetGroupProjPath">
    <ItemGroup>
      <DProjs Include="@(Projects->'$(GroupProjPath)%(FileName)%(Extension)')" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="GetDProjs">
    <Message Text="@(DProjs)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: @ChauCheeYang I know the above example answers your question, but it doesn't solve your problem. If you wan't to solve your problem you should call the default.groupproj directly with MsBuild 'msbuild "C:\development\project\default.groupproj"' since .group proj is an msbuild project, or you should try the answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865641/build-all-projects-in-a-directory

Comment: I am using multi-core CPU.  The default.groupproj from `Delphi` doesn't build all `dproj`s in parallel.  Only 1 task were executed at any time.  I am thinking to derive a new `msbuild` groupproj from original `default.groupproj` utilizing `BuildInParallel`.

Comment: @ChauCheeYang take a look at my edit. That should help you to build the projects in parallel.

Comment: Are you sure using `BuildInParallel="False"` will build project in parallel?

Comment: @ChauCheeYang you are right that's fixed now... Now the question is... Is this solving your problem?

Comment: The scripts almost correct except one thing.  `MsBuildProjectDirectory` is not the directory I want.  I want directory from $(GroupProj) in my original question.